# How to apply startOffset in the style-section of an svg for all textPath elements?

Tags: css, svg, text, styles, syntax-error

Putting the `startOffset`-setting in the `textPath`'s tag does work (`startOffset=" 20%"`)
But as I have quite a lot of textPaths, I want to put this setting in the style.

How to do that? Is it possible?

```html
<svg width="1059" height="637"  viewBox="0 0 1059 637" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>  <![CDATA[  * { font-family: Corbel;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;fill: #0000ff;text-anchor: start;white-space: pre;startOffset: 40%;method: align;text-decoration: none none;text-transform: none;font-variant: normal;text-shadow: none;word-spacing: 0px;letter-spacing: 0px;font-stretch: normal; }  
 textPath {  startOffset:" 20%" }     ]]> </style> 
<defs>
    <path id="a131" d="M46.5,172.5L57.5,172.5L63.5,172.5L65.5,172.5L72.5,172.5L73.5,172.5L77.5,172.5L82.5,172.5" />
</defs> 
<text>
    <textPath href="#a131">  Test Text                              Test Text</textPath>
</text> </svg>
```

Is it because it's an attribute instead of a property?

Comment: startOffset is an [attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextPathElementStartOffsetAttribute) and not a CSS property so cannot be set via CSS

Comment: @RobertLongson Indeed. I just found out. The other relevant attribute for me seems to be `method`. I found a site about [SVG presentation attributes are CSS properties that can be used as attributes on SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Presentation), but the other way around, using element-attributes as CSS properties doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startOffset` is an attribute and not a CSS property so cannot be set via CSS. (`method` seems to be another attribute relevant to my program.)

There are [SVG presentation attributes that are CSS properties that can be used as attributes on SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Presentation). The other way around that SVG elements' original attributes could be used in CSS styling, doesn't work.